# Drupal 7: Can I use a webform to submit a single record or upload CSV file for multiple records to database?

Tags: database, csv, drupal, drupal-7

A client has asked that we come up with a solution to the following scenario.

They would like a webform that would allow for single/multi-line record submission, which is easy enough to do. They would also like to have the ability to have a file upload option that would allow them to upload a CSV file for bulk record submission.

Has anyone else run into something like this? Is this something that can be done using the Drupal Feeds module? If so, how have you done it? If not... how have you done it?

Comment: Do you mean that CSV file uploading option is not available in webform or what?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to upload multiple CSV files in webform. I don't know why you are going for Feeds module. You have webform specific modules that is [webform_multiple](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multifile)  and [webform_multiple_file](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file). Please have a look into these modules it may resolve your problem.

Comment: Not trying to upload multiple CSV files. I need the ability to add a single record to the database via webform elements (textfield, select, etc.), but also the ability to add bulk records to the database via CSV upload.

Comment: @sixty7ss, CSV file also u can upload by using field type "File" in the webforms.

Comment: But will that automatically update the database with those records? Trying to figure out the automated process.

Comment: @sixty7ss, May I know what do you mean by updating the database with those records. As far as I know it will update the database with file location. Can you just try once by implementing this. Then u will get clear picture of its working or not.